# CSS присвоить псевдокласс второй строке таблицы без наследования

Tags: html, css3, table

Простите за дилетантский вопрос, только учусь. Вопрос упрощенный, есть таблица:

```
<table border="1" id="la_block">
<tr><th>ПОСЛЕДНИЕ ОТВЕТЫ</th></tr>
<tr><td> /*столбец для которой нужны стили*/
  <table border="1"><tr><td>Ответы</td></tr></table> /*дочерняя таблица*/
</td></tr> 
</table>
```

Необходимо через псевдокласс задать стили для td второй строки таблицы, но не затрагивать её дочернюю table, пробую так:

`#la_block tr:nth-child(2) td {padding:15px;}`

Но так затрагиваются стили дочерней таблицы.

Вот код на jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6zkg4xnL/1/

Comment: использовать знак >

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
#la_block>tbody>tr:nth-child(2)>td {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" id="la_block">
  <tr>
    <th>ПОСЛЕДНИЕ ОТВЕТЫ</th>
    <th>Just another cell</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table border="1">
        <tr>
          <td>Ответы</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ответы</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>Ещё ячейка</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: запарился на tbody)

Comment: @Jean-Claude, да, не стоит его забывать :)

Comment: Спасибо огромное )